# Get https://127.0.0.1:4001/health: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, kubernetes

When I check the status of etcd-0, its showing that the status is **unhealthy**.

```
[devops@devops kubernetes]$ kubectl get cs
NAME                 STATUS      MESSAGE   ERROR                                                                         
controller-manager   Healthy     ok
scheduler            Healthy     ok
etcd-0               Unhealthy   Get https://127.0.0.1:4001/health: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid
etcd-1               Unhealthy   Get https://127.0.0.1:4002/health: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid
```

Any idea, how to fix this,

Thanks,

Comment: Have you checked [Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62325448/12153576) answer?